# How to delete certain characters from multiple text files, in a thread safe way?

Tags: c++, multithreading

What is the best way, to develop a multi threaded program, to delete certain characters from multiple text files that are passed in as parameters?

Thus, when someone passes as a.out axvc f1 f2 f3 f4 , the goal is to delete all occurences of the characters a,x,v,c from the file f1, f2, f3 and f4.

Comment: One solution is to , create one thread for each file and do it. But what if one file is too big and the rest are too small. Are we not overloading one thread?

Comment: The task seems heavily I/O bound. I doubt you will see any benefit from splitting the work across multiple threads.

Comment: There would be a big speedup if the files are on different disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you not able to just make use of normal utilities like `sed` to help you do this?

Even if you aren't, are you sure that the CPU use is a significant enough portion of the processing time that it wouldn't be dwarfed by the file I/O? Most likely doing it in multiple threads won't save you much time at all vs doing it serially in one thread.

Otherwise probably the easiest mechanism would be to have the main thread doing the I/O and dispatching work to a pool of worker threads that do the character removal. It gets trickier if I/O speed actually improves when being done from multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you want to use multiple threads to do this? If the files are on the same device that won't help at all.